# Stop alphanumeric force sort for subreport in SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2008-r2, ssrs-2012, alphanumeric

I have a subreport that prints out a shipping label in SSRS.  It takes an Order # as a parameter.  I have another report that allows for multiple orders to be entered in as one parameter (separated by commas) and then using this

```
=Split(UCase(Parameters!OrderNo.Value), ",")
```

runs through each of the order #s in the parameter string and churns out the subreport (shipping label) for each order #.

The problem is that the orders come out in alphanumeric order, NOT the order I type them in.

E.G., if order # parameter is 'A04, A1, A01' the labels get printed in this order: A01, A04, A1.  I want them to print out A04, A1, A01.

How can I eliminate the alphanumeric sort it is doing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out.  I had the output tablix (that contained the subreport) grouped on Order # and for that row group, I entered in the following for the sort expression:

`=Array.IndexOf(Split(Parameters!OrderNo.Value, ","),Fields!ORDER_NO.Value)`

Basically sorting on the index of the order # in the parameter.  Worked like a charm.